ASP.NET Core Identity with Google authentication
We have an ASP.NET Core application with ASP.NET Core Identity and we want users to authenticate only with Google (no login form).
We configured the authentication like this:
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
  {
      options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
      options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
  })
.AddCookie()
.AddGoogle(options =>
{
    options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
    options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
});

// ....

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

// ....

And this is the HomeController :
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public HomeController()
    {
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
       return View();
    }
}

It works well without calling to  :
services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
    .AddErrorDescriber<LocalizedIdentityErrorDescriber>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

It goes to google and get authenticated but the signin-google seems not able to set the authentication cookies or something.
It keeps a loop of redirect between home index and google many times and then threw error of :

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
AuthenticationFailureException: Correlation failed. Unknown location
AuthenticationFailureException: An error was encountered while
handling the remote login.


If without google, Asp.net  core identity's AddIdentity will still register a cookiescheme CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme by default to use.
So the google auth need to add another cookieschme. But AddCookie() equals to AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) by default. It will cause conflict with "asp.net core identity cookie". You need give it another name. And specify the new cookieschme in google auth configuration.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(
    options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = "googleAuthCookie";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }
    ).AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
{
    googleOptions.ClientId = "xxx";
    googleOptions.ClientSecret = "xxx";
    googleOptions.SignInScheme = "googleAuthCookie";
})
    .AddCookie("googleAuthCookie");

